# como obtener todo el texto de un elemento HTML desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente HTML:

```html
<div id='id'>
   Algo
</div>
```

Y el siguiente Javascript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("id");
console.log(el.innerHTML);
```

Me da "Algo", pero quiero que me de `<div id='id'>Algo</div>` como lo hago?
Intente con simplemente `el`, pero solo me da un objeto de tipo HTMLDivElement y quiero que me de un string, intente con `String(el)` o `el.toString()`, pero me da `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`

Comment: @BetaM Me da lo mismo, un HTMLDivElement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2470148 ó https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819589

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `textContent` y `outerHTML` para obtener lo que buscas:

```js
document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = document.getElementById("id").outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id='id'>
   Algo
</div>
<div id='resultado'>
</div>
```

Comment: pero eso daria un objeto HTML y yo quiero que me de un string

Comment: @BenjaminAlexisRivasBeltran entiendo, por favor edita tu pregunta y detalla eso.

Comment: @BenjaminAlexisRivasBeltran por favor revisa la edición y me comentas.

Comment: funciono gracias

Answer (score 1):

La única manera que se me ocurre en que puedes obtener el resultado que estas buscando es agregar un `div` como elemento padre de tu elemento actual de esta manera puedes acceder al `innerHTML` del elemento padre de tu selección y te retornaría un strign como el que buscas.
Tu elemento deberia quedar de la siguiente manera:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('id');
console.log(element.parentElement.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='id'>
    Algo
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda mi respuesta.

Comment: Recuerda que existe [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), de tal forma que no es necesario envolver el elemento en otro. Saludos

Comment: Orale no conocía eso muchas gracias